# "regrettably" vs "regretfully"

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

These two words have been haunting me for quite long. Please provide some logic to understand and use them efficiently.

Ex: Regrettably/Regretfully, she could not see her father for the last time.

Comment: Regrettably, she would not see her father again.  (After all, she did at some time see her father for the last time.)

Comment: Did you try looking them up in a dictionary? If so, what was confusing about what you found?

Answer (score 34):

*Garner's Modern American Usage* (p705) has an entry on the two words:

> Errors made are *regrettable*; the people who made them should be *regretful*. The most common error is to misuse *regretful* for *regrettable*, particularly in the adverbial forms.

So you need *regrettably* in your example:

> Regrettably, she could not see her father for the last time.

*Regretfully* is less likely to start a sentence. A possible example is:

> Regretfully she admitted to having been unkind to her father the last time she saw him.

Comment: The different usages are brought out by the use of the comma in the pragmatic marker usage (_Regrettably,_), which is a comment showing the writer's / speaker's feelings on the matter. _Regretfully_ here is a true adverb modifying _admitted_.

Comment: While the final example is grammatically sound and illustrates the point, in actual practice it might be preferable to write "She regretfully admitted". This makes it clear that the author's intention is to indicate her admitting something in a regretful tone of voice, rather than making the error of misusing "regretfully" for "regrettably".

Comment: @jmbpiano. I agree that _She regretfully admitted_ is less likely to be misinterpreted than _Regretfully she admitted_. Certainly, this Google sentence ( _Regretfully she declined his invitation to return home_.) prompts the question: _Did she decline the invitation with regret?_ Or _Is it regrettable that she declined it_?

Comment: Ironically, "regrettably, she could not see her father for the last time", is not a reasonable statement. She either has, or will, see her father for the last time, or never saw her father. If she ever saw her father, it's not possible for her to "not see her father for the last time", as there will *always* be a last time that she saw her father. What was probably meant was that she could not go to a meeting between her and her father which they had planned as the last time that she would see him. While the statement might be interpreted to make sense in context, out of context it doesn't.

Comment: @Makyen While I see where you're going (and you are technically correct) I disagree that the statement doesn't make sense.  I feel that any native English speaker, upon hearing the statement, would immediately understand the intended meaning regardless of there being any other context.  I certainly understood the meaning, as has most others here (yourself included) it would appear.

Comment: Please don't answer questions which blatantly violate the site rules.

Answer (score 17):

A situation can *be* regrettable. A person can *feel* regretful.

Answer (score 9):

[Shoe](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/421645/191178) is right that the adjectives *regretful* and *regrettable* cannot be used interchangeably:

> The adjectives regretful and regrettable are distinct in meaning: regretful means ‘feeling or showing regret’, as in she shook her head with a regretful smile, while regrettable means ‘giving rise to regret; undesirable’, as in the loss of jobs is regrettable.
> <sub>[ODO: regretfully](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/regretfully)</sub>

However, it is not true that the adverbs *regrettably* and *regretfully* have the same distinction, at least in non-formal contexts:

> The adverbs regretfully and regrettably have not, however, preserved the same distinction. Regretfully is used as a normal adverb to mean ‘in a regretful manner’ (he sighed regretfully), but it is also used as a sentence adverb meaning ‘it is regrettable that’ (regretfully, mounting costs forced the branch to close). In this latter use it is synonymous with regrettably. This is disliked by traditionalists and should be avoided in formal contexts.
> <sub>ibid</sub>

#### Unless you are writing formally, you can use either in your sentence. In formal writing use *regrettably*.

Comment: Please don't answer questions which blatantly violate the site rules.

Answer (score 2):

Both words have the same root: regret, meaning to feel sadness, repentance, or disappointment, but they each have their own way of dealing with it.

Regrettably describes something that deserves regret, and is used like the word "unfortunately." Regrettably is like bad luck, and it often kicks off a sentence:

For reference:

https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/regrettably-regretfully/

Answer (score 2):

"Regrettably" is used for a situation that is unfortunately not as you would like it to be. It doesn't assign any fault, and doesn't say you could have done anything differently.

"Regretfully" is used if there is a regrettable situation, you caused it, and you are sorry that you caused it.

"Regrettable" describes a situation, "regretfully" describes the feelings of the person who caused it.